# Display Ads Medium Showing CPC instead of CPM

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, utm-parameters

For my Google Ads, I'm using a tracking template to apply *utm_medium=cpm* to designate display ads in Google Analytics. *utm_medium=cpc* designates text ads. However, it appears as though Analytics is reporting that information as medium cpc.

Is this due to using Google Analytics auto-tagging, or is there some other reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be the default setting in Google Ads: "Settings" (on left nav) > "Account Settings" (top tab) > "Auto-tagging."